# How to connect zend framework to database?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, database-connection

I installed LAMP on a fresh server and Zend Framework aswell. I now want to connect to my database using

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db'); // Starts connection
$db -> query($query); // Runs the connection
```

I had coders set up my site, now that I'm trying to setup everything on my own. I can't find where they're connecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html).

You might want to take a look at your application `Bootstrap`, or your configuration files as it can be setup in either of them.

The part that's actually binding the configuration and creating your adapter is `Zend_Application_Resource_Db` (<del>in 1.11 anyway</del> [since 1.8](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.8/en/zend.application.available-resources.html))

** **EDIT** **

One way to understand ZF's inner working is to walk the bootstrap process (starting with your `/index.php` file (should be in `/public` or whatever your public folder name is). Locating your configuration files should also be a good starting point as they contain valuable information about your application resources. Those files should be in your application root directory, somewhere.

Comment: yo genius, @soulkphp I did read it, I can't find the connection it's talking about in my live working site. Yet it's connecting. None of my codes display where it's selecting a database or anything.

Comment: @Yanick Alright, I've been using an old version of Zend Framework on the live site. The new one connects differently apparently, I was trying to keep it as close to original as possible. Looks like I need to make quite a few changes. So if I put the connection in the bootstrap, it should work from what you're saying. Thanks!

Comment: @Darius, which version of ZF are you using?

Comment: I have 1.5.2 installed on the live server. I just installed the latest one on the fresh server.

Comment: there are quite few changes since 1.5.2! I hope your project is not too far gone!

Comment: It's gone very far sadly =[ That's why I'm having such a headache and trouble now. Hopefully I'll be able to fix it all up... or convert over. Thanks for your help Yanick.